# Custom indent for default xmlns attribute wile writing through XmlWriter

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

I'm struggling a bit trying to find the appropriate way of writing exactly this XML with XmlWriter and underlying string builder:

```
<x:node xmlns="uri:default"
        xmlns:x="uri:special-x"
        xmlns:y="uri:special-y"
        y:name="MyNode"
        SomeOtherAttr="ok">
</x:node>
```

The best I have so far:

```
static string GetXml()
{
    var r = new StringBuilder();
    var w = XmlWriter.Create(r, new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true });
    w.WriteStartElement("x", "node", "uri:special-x");
    w.Flush();
    r.Append("\n" + new string(' ', 7));
    w.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "x", null, "uri:special-x");
    w.Flush();
    r.Append("\n" + new string(' ', 7));
    w.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "y", null, "uri:special-y");
    w.Flush();
    r.Append("\n" + new string(' ', 7));
    w.WriteAttributeString("name", "uri:special-y", "vd");
    w.Flush();
    r.Append("\n" + new string(' ', 7));
    w.WriteAttributeString("SomeOtherAttr", "ok");
    w.Flush();
    w.WriteEndElement();
    w.Flush();
    return r.ToString();
}
```

which creates

```
<x:node
        xmlns:x="uri:special-x"
        xmlns:y="uri:special-y"
        y:name="vd"
        SomeOtherAttr="ok" />
```

but I cannot find a way to write default xmlns right after the node. Any try leads to error or different formatting.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Update: maybe I can write it directly to the StringBuilder but I look for more... hm.. correct approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to actually add your default namespace, which you're currently not doing:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, new XmlWriterSettings
{
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
});

using (writer)
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("x", "node", "uri:special-x");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "uri:default");
    writer.Flush();
    sb.Append("\n" + new string(' ', 7));
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "x", null, "uri:special-x");
    writer.Flush();
    sb.Append("\n" + new string(' ', 7));
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "y", null, "uri:special-y");
    writer.Flush();
    sb.Append("\n" + new string(' ', 7));
    writer.WriteAttributeString("name", "uri:special-y", "vd");
    writer.Flush();
    sb.Append("\n" + new string(' ', 7));
    writer.WriteAttributeString("SomeOtherAttr", "ok");            
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

See this demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/994YqW

That being said, why are you trying to do this?  Just let it format it how it likes, it's still semantically the same and perfectly valid.

Comment: I need to compare many WPF files and want to convert them to the "canonical" form to simplify it and potentially use the result as auto-formatting tool for the project files. For this the documents should be formatted in the way VS/Resharper does it + some "canonical" rules like ordered attributes etc.

Comment: That makes some sense. Normally XML isn't for human consumption, but XAML is a bit of a special case!

Answer (score 1):

Why so hard?
Try this please:

```
var r = new StringBuilder();

var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
    NewLineOnAttributes = true,
    Indent = true,
    IndentChars = "\t"
};

using (var w = XmlWriter.Create(r, settings))
{
    w.WriteStartElement("x", "node", "uri:special-x");

    w.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "x", null, "uri:special-x");
    w.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "y", null, "uri:special-y");
    w.WriteAttributeString("name", "uri:special-y", "vd");
    w.WriteAttributeString("SomeOtherAttr", "ok");

    w.WriteEndElement();
}
```

All namespaces will be on one line.

Comment: Thanks, nice one. Is there anything like NewLineOnAttributes but for namespaces as well?

Comment: @AlexAtNet Unfortunately no.